# Has anything changed on Parse to invalidate SSL certificate?

Tags: security, parse-platform, ssl-certificate

I developed an embedded device that communicates with api.parse.com.   I required a certificate to be held on the embedded system to use the SSL connection to Parse.   I got the certificate from Parse and the expiration date was some time in 2031.

On Aug. 11th all my embedded systems stop communication to Parse.  Debugging shows it fails to make an SSL connection.

My question is has anything happen on Parse to change that certificate of change the SSL in any way? I need to get the devices back up and running.

Comment: Looking at api.parse.com the certificate is now set to expire in 2016. I'd assume this is because many browsers are now marking certificates with far away expiration dates as insecure.

Comment: Do you get a specific error when the SSL connection fails? What OS and library are you using?